# Add a substring based on a condition in r

Tags: r, substring, data-cleaning

I would like to add a substring add the end of a string variable in my data. This variable represents a question asked during a specific case and can be either irrelevant ("00"), partially relevant ("01") or very relevant ("02"). Hence I would like to make this a conditional statement based on the specific value of the case ID. Here is some sample data:

| Case_ID | Question |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | QS1 |
| 4321 | QS1 |
| 1234 | QS3 |
| 1234 | QS2 |
| 4321 | QS3 |
| 4321 | QS2 |

Where:
Case_ID 1234: QS1 very relevant ("02") , QS2 irrelevant ("00"), QS3 irrelevant ("00) AND
Case_ID 4321: QS1 irrelevant ("00"), QS2 partially relevant ("01"), QS3 very relevant ("02).

I hope to receive the following output:

| Case_ID | Question |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | QS102 |
| 4321 | QS100 |
| 1234 | QS300 |
| 1234 | QS200 |
| 4321 | QS302 |
| 4321 | QS201 |

Comment: By what logic do you determine which case IDs are relevant?

Comment: @r2evans the logic is predetermined by an external source

Comment: How do you suppose we are supposed to suggest code that implements logic not clearly defined in the question?

Comment: Do you have some sort of lookup table, maybe a data frame with all case IDs in one column and a `relevance` column with the corresponding 00, 01, 02 codes? Or a vector of case IDs, one for each relevance code? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a very 'by hand' solution with `if` statements

```
df = tibble(
  Case_ID = c(1234, 4321,    1234,  1234,    4321,  4321),
  Question = c("QS1", "QS1", "QS3", "QS2", "QS3", "QS2"))

relevance = function(case, question) {
  if(case == 1234) {
    if(question == "QS1") {"02"}
    else {"00"}}
  else {
    if(question == "QS1") {"00"}
    else if(question == "QS2") {"01"}
    else {"02"}}}

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Question = paste0(Question, relevance(Case_ID, Question)))

# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Rowwise: 
  Case_ID Question
    <dbl> <chr>   
1    1234 QS102   
2    4321 QS100   
3    1234 QS300   
4    1234 QS200   
5    4321 QS302   
6    4321 QS201
```

Comment: re: `if(case == 1234)`: I think this solution only works for the example data? In some ways reasonable because there's not sufficient data to answer the question otherwise. But I don't think it's what our asker is looking for.

Comment: @CaptainHat I agree. If there was a lookup table there could be a more general answer, but as OP said, the conditions are "predetermined by an external source", so i wanted to show he could "hard code" them with if statements. If he needs, he can change the conditions with the values from his actual dataset. Still, if this answer is misleading i can delete it.

Comment: Hard-coding with `if` statements is a bug-prone and labor-intensive way to go about this. It would be more maintainable (and probably easier) to build a look-up table, even manually, based on the external source.